# Angularjs material design input not working even after loading css and js files

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

This my code.... in this material css is not geting applied to input fields and they are appearing as normal html inputs.

I have used material css and js cdns and both of them are same versions. I dont know why its not working. I checked other posts in stackoverflow but i didn't got the solution. so, Somebody please help me with this thing...

```js
var app = angular.module('sdp', ['ngMaterial']).config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('custom')
.primaryPalette('blue')
.accentPalette('indigo');
}).controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

```css
.header {
            text-align: center;
            height: 80px;
            margin-left: 555px !important;
            line-height: 80px;
            color:white;
        }

        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #111;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #94bddb), color-stop(100%, #d9edf9));
            background-size: cover;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Login to Data Portal</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="sdp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <md-toolbar style="background: #174a7a;">
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                <h1 class="header">LOGIN</h1>
            </div>
        </md-toolbar>
    </div>
    <div>
        <md-card >
            <md-card-content>
                <md-card-title>
                    <md-card-title-text>
                        <span class="md-headline">Card</span>
                    </md-card-title-text>
                </md-card-title>
                <ng-form name="colorForm">
                    <div layout-gt-xs="row">
                        <md-input-container>
                            <label> Username </label>
                            <input ng-model="un" required>
                        </md-input-container>
                        
                         <md-input-container>
                            <label> Password </label>
                            <input ng-model="pswd" required>
                        </md-input-container>
                    </div>
                </ng-form>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've placed the `ng-app` on your toolbar `div`, so your AngularJS app is only working inside that part of the page.

Remove it from there and add it to your `body` tag to have it affect all of your page, like so:

```
<body ng-app="sdp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    ...
```

Here's the full code with the change:

```js
var app = angular.module('sdp', ['ngMaterial']).config(function ($mdThemingProvider) {
    $mdThemingProvider.theme('custom')
      .primaryPalette('blue')
      .accentPalette('indigo');
}).controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

```css
.header {
    text-align: center;
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 555px !important;
    line-height: 80px;
    color:white;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #111;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #94bddb), color-stop(100%, #d9edf9));
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <title>Login to Data Portal</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="sdp">
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          <md-toolbar style="background: #174a7a;">
              <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                  <h1 class="header">LOGIN</h1>
              </div>
          </md-toolbar>
      </div>
      <div>
          <md-card >
              <md-card-content>
                  <md-card-title>
                      <md-card-title-text>
                          <span class="md-headline">Card</span>
                      </md-card-title-text>
                  </md-card-title>
                  <ng-form name="colorForm">
                      <div layout-gt-xs="row">
                          <md-input-container>
                              <label> Username </label>
                              <input ng-model="un" required>
                          </md-input-container>

                           <md-input-container>
                              <label> Password </label>
                              <input ng-model="pswd" required>
                          </md-input-container>
                      </div>
                  </ng-form>
              </md-card-content>
          </md-card>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did like that but still not working i have also tried refreshing browser cache

Comment: The snippet I attached isn't working for you? it's working fine for me.